# Jenkins + Concordion + Ant

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, concordion

I am trying to use Concordion plugin for Jenkins to get acceptance tests reports there. Anyone has any idea what to include in the build.xml file for Ant? I guess if I manage to run the acceptance test, the html report will be generated and then I can point Jenkins to get it right?

I have followed [Getting Started](http://badrobot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bad.robot/concordion-ant-task/manual/bad/robot/concordion/ant/manual/GettingStarted.html) with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, my apologies for my bad english.

I dit recently that stuff. I explain you how i did it.

Well, in my build.xml i created the next task

```
<!-- Run the Acceptance Tests --> 
<target name="tests-aceptacion"> 
    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes">
        <sysproperty key="concordion.output.dir" value="${test.accept.report.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="junit.class.path" /> 
        <classpath> 
            <pathelement location="${build.test.accept.dir}"/> 
        </classpath> 
        <formatter type="xml" /> 
        <formatter type="plain" />
        <batchtest todir="${test.accept.report.dir}"> 
            <fileset dir="${test.accept.dir}"> 
                <include name="**/EspecificacionesFixture.java" /> 
            </fileset> 
        </batchtest> 
    </junit> 
</target>
```

With this task, i execute my EspecificacionesFixture class, that is the parent class of all my specifications, so it executes all specifications, and the outputs is left in ${test.accept.report.dir} folder.

Then, in Jenkins, you must download the HTML Publisher plugin, and then you must configure it correctly in your Jenkins task.

You can view the next link for configure it correctly
http://blog.shinetech.com/2014/05/09/concordion-integration-with-jenkins/

I hope it can help you.